# Move resources from one resource group to another

Tags: powershell, azure

I was searching the Steps to Move resources from one resource group to another on Azure and found [this](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/6178622-ability-to-move-resources-from-one-resource-group) - saying work in progress to achieve it through Azure portal since May 04, 2015

Just wanted to know if we have any other way (SDKs, Azure Powershell etc) to achieve the same?

Much appreciated if you could share the steps in an eloborated way, so that I think it would useful for the future referrers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can move resources from one resource group to another in the same or other subscription though there are some restrictions on what all resource types can be moved and what all resource types can be moved across subscription. You can do it through Azure Portal, PowerShell as well as using Azure Resource Manager REST API. Please see this blog post for more details on how to do this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

Comment: Thanks. let me read it and try, Gaurav. I'll update you if If face any issues on the same. (look for your full support on the same)... +1