# NoDomainNamesToMove - Could not move resources to new group in azure portal

Tags: powershell, azure

I am following below link to move resources from one group to new group.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

Getting below error

> There was an error moving resources. Resources xxxxx' could not be moved. (Code: ResourceMoveFailed) Move request contains virtual machines but not the domain names. (Code: NoDomainNamesToMove

I already referenced [Move resources from one resource group to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449325/move-resources-from-one-resource-group-to-another) but no help

I am using new portal. https://portal.azure.com

what does "***move request contains virtual machines but not the domain names***" means?

I tried power shell for switching to **Resource Manager** as follow

> S C:> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager

But getting below error

> Switch-AzureMode : The term 'Switch-AzureMode' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. We have to select **Cloud service** along with the resource we planning to move.

In new portal

1. Click the EDIT button (Pencil Icon) next to Resource group name
2. New blade will be opened, select the cloud service. do not select the storage account.
3. Select group listed in drop down.
4. Click OK.